# Why is shutter speed changing after each shot in manual mode?

Tags: shutter-speed, manual-mode, nikon-d7100

I set my D7100 to M (manual), set the aperture to f5.6 and the shutter to 1/250. After I take a picture the shutter speed changes.  Is this normal?

Comment: What shutter speed was actually used when the photo was exposed?

Comment: To what setting was the shutter speed changed?

Comment: Do you have auto-bracketing enabled?

Comment: Do you have the flash enabled?

Answer (score 15):

No, it is not normal. One thing that Manual mode is used for is to take multiple photographs with the same exposure parameters which is very useful in many situations. There are a few cases where it may happen though. If you are bracketing for exposure, then one of the exposure-parameters, usually shutter-speed, is changed between frames until the bracket is entirely taken.

Some cameras have a feature called something like *Exposure Safety* which adjusts exposure on your behalf if the exposure you chose does not match the metered one. Check if you have that option in the setup menu and if it is disabled, should it be there.

Comment: Thank you very much - I am new to this camera and I had enabled bracketing.  I disabled it and the shutter speed no longer changed.

Answer (score 4):

I have a D7000 and it does it when the bracketing is on.  Check this setting I think it will be the same on the D7100 too .

Comment: Thank you so much! I changed my stings and now shutter speed is fixed.