# How do I lock the shutter speed on a Nikon D90?

Tags: shutter-speed, nikon-d90

I don't know how to lock the shutter speed on a Nikon D90. Any time I take a picture, the shutter speed changes automatically even if it's on Manual mode. Any way to lock it?

Comment: Have you seen the answer and comments to this question? http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/72666/why-is-shutter-speed-changing-after-each-shot-in-manual-mode

Answer (score 2):

If a manual shutter speed is changing, then you have Bracketing turned on.  Turn bracketing off.  Change number of bracketed shots to be zero.